# Absolutely positioned pseudo element acts as block element in flex container in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I could swear this wasn't an issue back when I wrote the code few months ago, but today I noticed bunch of my code started misbehaving in IE. I've tracked the issue down to CSS - `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between`.

I have a navigation container with left and right menu and a pseudo element that is used for background transition. In IE the pseudo element acts as a block element so the children of the container are aligned as if there were three items and not just two.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qasm1zcu/) and also you can [view this in IE vs Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/qasm1zcu/embedded/result,css,html,js).

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>
    LEFT
  </p>
  <p>
    RIGHT
  </p>
</nav>
```

Opera, Edge, Firefox work same as Chrome. Result in Chrome:

[image]

Result in IE:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is known to have a lot of *flex bugs*. Here instead of `justify-content: space-between` you can use `margin-right: auto` on the first `p` element to get the same effect.

See demo below and [**`updated fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/te3uo0y6/):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav p:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>LEFT</p>
  <p>RIGHT</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I was busy with other things. Yeah I'll probably have to use this workaround. But what I don't understand is that we had QA that checks IE about 5 months ago and they didnt report this. right now I have a logo centered on bunch of pages in IE :D so what I was more ineterested in was to find out if there could have been any updates to IE, but I thought those dont come out anymore.